d3js semi-pie chart with a seamless wiggle rainbow color pattern
I am experimenting with different styles for charts - and I am wondering how to create these kind of pattern textures charts for the different segments with rounded gapped edges (maybe using cornerRadius(10)).
I've made a version which appends a pattern to the arcs - but I am unsure how to style it further to get the demo replica.
-1 how to create this specific wiggly pattern that rainbows - this doesn't angle.
-2 corner round the segments

my current build -- regular arc
I've seen this example in making a pattern - how would you make this wiggly multi-colored pattern that covers the arcs - almost like its cut out and there is this pattern behind it
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-wiles-forked-hdpq79
import React from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import "./SemiPieChart1.scss";

class SemiPieChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      theme: this.props.theme
        ? this.props.theme
        : ["#bde0fe", "#2698f9", "#71bcfd", "#f1f8fe"],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var $this = this.myRef.current;

    d3.select($this).selectAll("svg").remove();

    const data = this.props.data;

    const width = parseInt(this.props.width, 10),
      height = parseInt(this.props.height, 10),
      radius = parseInt(this.props.r, 10),
      innerradius = parseInt(this.props.ir, 10);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(this.state.theme);

    var arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius).innerRadius(innerradius);

    data.forEach(function (d) {
      d.total = +d.value;
    });

    var pie = d3
      .pie()
      .startAngle(-90 * (Math.PI / 180))
      .endAngle(90 * (Math.PI / 180))
      .padAngle(0.02) // some space between slices
      .sort(null)
      .value(function (d) {
        return d.total;
      });

    var svg = d3
      .select($this)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "piechart")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var segments = svg.append("g").attr("class", "segments");

    var slices = segments
      .selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    slices
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return color(i);
      })
      .transition()
      .attrTween("d", function (d) {
        var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle + 0.1, d.endAngle);
        return function (t) {
          d.endAngle = i(t);
          return arc(d);
        };
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} className="SemiPieChart" />;
  }
}
export default SemiPieChart;



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="hook"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        // SVG injection:
var svg = d3.select("#hook").append("svg").attr("id", "d3svg")
    .attr("width", 120)
    .attr("height", 120);
//Pattern injection
var defs = svg.append("defs")
var pattern = defs.append("pattern")
        .attr({ id:"hash4_4", width:"8", height:"8", patternUnits:"userSpaceOnUse", patternTransform:"rotate(-45)"})
    .append("rect")
        .attr({ width:"4", height:"8", transform:"translate(0,0)", fill:"#88AAEE" });

//Shape design
svg.append("g").attr("id","shape")
    .append("circle")
.attr({cx:"60",cy:"60",r:"50", fill:"url(#hash4_4)" })
    </script>
</body>
</html>



Found this as a reference -- but not sure how to make those exact patterns in the demo
How to make the patterns of a pie chart parallel to the center line of sectors in d3.js?


<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.15.1/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg id="pie" width="300" height="200"> </svg>
<svg id="legend">
    
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern0);" />   
    <rect x="100" y="0" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />   
        <rect x="200" y="0" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern2);" />   
</svg>

<script>
    var data = [{ year: '2001', value:10 },
            { year: '2002', value:30 },
            { year: '2003', value:60 },
           ]

    var svg = d3.select("svg#pie"),
        width = svg.attr("width"),
        height = svg.attr("height"),
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(['#4daf4a','#377eb8','#ff7f00','#984ea3','#e41a1c']);

    // Generate the pie
    var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) { 
    return d.value;})(data);

    // Generate the patterns
    var legend = d3.select("svg#legend"),
        defs = legend.append("defs");
    defs.selectAll("pattern")
        .data(pie)
        .enter()
        .append("pattern")
        .attr("id", (d, i) => "pattern" + i)
        .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("patternTransform", (d) => `rotate(${(d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI})`)
        .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
             .append("rect")
             .attr("x", 5)
             .attr("y", 5)
             .attr("width", 10)
             .attr("height", 10)

    // Generate the arcs
    var arc = d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(0)
                .outerRadius(radius);

    //Generate groups
    var arcs = g.selectAll("arc")
                .data(pie)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc")

    //Draw arc paths
    arcs.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
  .attr('stroke', "black")
            .attr('stroke-width', '1')
            .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return  "url(#pattern" + i +")"});
</script>
</script>



19th Sep -- this is the latest version that patterns the arcs - but I am not sure how to style it further to get it closer to the demo.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-wiles-forked-6kdkf8

import React from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import "./SemiPieChart1.scss";

class SemiPieChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      theme: this.props.theme
        ? this.props.theme
        : ["#bde0fe", "#2698f9", "#71bcfd", "#f1f8fe"],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var $this = this.myRef.current;

    d3.select($this).selectAll("svg").remove();

    const data = this.props.data;

    const width = parseInt(this.props.width, 10),
      height = parseInt(this.props.height, 10),
      radius = parseInt(this.props.r, 10),
      innerradius = parseInt(this.props.ir, 10);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(this.state.theme);

    var arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius).innerRadius(innerradius);

    data.forEach(function (d) {
      d.total = +d.value;
    });

    var pie = d3
      .pie()
      .startAngle(-90 * (Math.PI / 180))
      .endAngle(90 * (Math.PI / 180))
      .padAngle(0.02) // some space between slices
      .sort(null)
      .value(function (d) {
        return d.total;
      });

    var svg = d3
      .select($this)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "piechart")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    // Generate the patterns
    var legend = d3.select("svg#legend"),
      defs = legend.append("defs");
    defs
      .selectAll("pattern")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append("pattern")
      .attr("id", (d, i) => "pattern" + i)
      .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr(
        "patternTransform",
        (d) => `rotate(${((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90) / Math.PI})`
      )
      .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 5)
      .attr("y", 5)
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10);

    var segments = svg.append("g").attr("class", "segments");

    var slices = segments
      .selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    slices
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return color(i);
      })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", "1")
      .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return "url(#pattern" + i + ")";
      })
      .transition()
      .attrTween("d", function (d) {
        var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle + 0.1, d.endAngle);
        return function (t) {
          d.endAngle = i(t);
          return arc(d);
        };
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <svg id="legend">
          <rect
            x="0"
            y="0"
            width="100"
            height="100"
            style={{ stroke: "#000000", fill: "url(#pattern0)" }}
          />
        </svg>
        <div ref={this.myRef} className="SemiPieChart" />
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default SemiPieChart;

research into rounded corners
https://medium.com/@bryony_17728/d3-donut-rounded-corners-the-mystery-of-pi-f772121d87a6
Add border-radius property to D3js Donut Chart
"can apply a corner radius to a d3 arc which allows rounding on the corners:"
let arc = d3.svg
    .arc()
    .innerRadius(23)
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .cornerRadius(10);


"If you apply the cornerRadius to only the darkened arc - the other
arc won't fill in the background behind the rounded corners. Instead,
we could append a circular arc (full donut) and place the darkened arc
on top with rounding (my example doesn't adapt your code, just shows
how that it can be done, also with d3v4 which uses d3.arc() rather
than d3.svg.arc() ):"



var backgroundArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(30)
  .outerRadius(50)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(Math.PI*2);
  
var mainArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(30)
  .outerRadius(50)
  .cornerRadius(10)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(function(d) { return d/100*Math.PI* 2 });
  
var data = [10,20,30,40,50] // percents.
  
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 200);
  
var charts = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",function(d,i) { 
     return "translate("+(i*100+50)+",100)";
  });
  
charts.append("path")
  .attr("d", backgroundArc)
  .attr("fill","#ccc")

charts.append("path")
  .attr("d", mainArc) 
  .attr("fill","orange")
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>



